# VBA ADO pass array parameter to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, t-sql, ado

I have an array with 3 column and 100K of rows in VBA MS Excel file.

I want to pass this array to SQL Server Stored Procedure and in the Stored Procedure to convert it to Tmp-table and do my "things.."

How do I pass an array to Stored Procedure ?

This is an example of my VBA array:

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 
1      AAA     XXX
2      BBB     YYY
3      CCC     ZZZ
```

The VBA code:

```
......

Set Cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

Cmd.CommandType = 4 
Cmd.NamedParameters = True
Cmd.ActiveConnection = DbConn
Cmd.CommandText = "My_SP_WithArrayParam"

''I dont know what parameters to use here:
Cmd.Parameters.Append Cmd.CreateParameter("@Arr", ??? , ?? , ??? , My_100K_Arr)

Cmd.Execute
```

And in the SQL side :

```
Create or alter proc My_SP_WithArrayParam(
                                            @Arr ???
                                            )
as 
begin
    create table #Tbl_From_Excel (
                                ID int
                                ,COL1 nvarchar(60)
                                ,COL2 nvarchar(60)
                                )

    ---Need to insert the array to the tmp table, and I dont know the syntax

end
```

Comment: SQL Server has no "array" object type. What you want to use is a Table Type parameter.

Comment: @Larnu , ok, and to Table Type I can pass my VBA array ?

Comment: Why not use text in json format with the content of your array and pass it as text. Sql Server starting from version 13 can handle json. This is [link](https://dymeng.com/parsing-json-with-vba/) may be useful.

Comment: @AntonGrig - it will be slow procdure to convert 100K * 3 values to JSON, and send a massive string to SQL, I tested a simular approach with convert the array to "insert into" string and it took 7 min to become a string

Comment: Sending 100,000 rows as a table type parameter wouldn't be performant either. I smell an XY problem.

Comment: @xl0911, but have you tried json? A TVP might be better but the VBA ADO might present a challenge with that.

Comment: @xl0911, fyi, I just ran a quick test with an array of 100K json objects like your example and it parsed in 3 seconds.

Comment: @DanGuzman I will be happy if can post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array of objects can be passed as a a structured parameter value, such as a table-valued parameter, XML, or json (SQL 2016 and later). Although newer SQL Server drivers support table-valued parameters, ADODB (a.k.a. ADO classic) does not. I suggest a json string over XML since it has a smaller payload and is parsed efficiently by SQL Server.

Below is VBA example code. The SQL call only took a few seconds but building the json string with traditional string concatenation took a couple of minutes on my workstation. Performant string building in VBA requires much attention to detail but it seems there are [techniques to improve it considerably](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67596/a-lightning-fast-stringbuilder) if you want to go there.

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC My_SP_WithArrayParam
    @Arr nvarchar(MAX)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
    INTO #Tbl_From_Excel 
FROM OPENJSON(@arr)
WITH (
     Col1 int
    ,Col2 varchar(100)
    ,Col3 varchar(100)
);
GO
```

ArrayEntry class:

```
Option Explicit

Public Col1 As Long
Public Col2 As String
Public Col3 As String

Public Function getJson()
    Dim json As String
    ` note if double quotes may exist in values, they need to be escaped with a backslash
    ' TODO: string building optimization
    getJson = "{""Col1"":""" & CStr(Col1) & """,""Col2"":""" & Col2 & """,""Col3"":""" & Col3 & """}"
End Function
```

Sample usage code:

```
' load 100000 array entries
Dim arrayEntries(100000) As ArrayEntry
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To 99999
    Set entry = New ArrayEntry
    Set arrayEntries(i) = entry
    entry.Col1 = i
    entry.Col2 = "AAA"
    entry.Col3 = "XXX"
Next i

' build json from array (TODO: string building optimization)
Dim json As String
json = "["
For i = 0 To 99999
    Set entry = arrayEntries(i)
    If i > 0 Then json = json & ","
    json = json & entry.getJson()
Next
json = json & "]"

' call proc with json parameter
con.Open "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
cmd.ActiveConnection = con
cmd.CommandText = "My_SP_WithArrayParam"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@json", adVarChar, adParamInput, -1, json)
cmd.Execute
con.Close
Set cmd = Nothing
Set con = Nothing
```